# Integrate other html documentation into sphinx docs

Tags: python, html, code-coverage, python-sphinx, nose

How do you include html docs generated by other tools such as nose, coverage, and pylint reports into Sphinx documentation. Should they go into the _static directory? and if so, how do you link to them?

I am trying to build a concise package of all of the code development tool documentation into a .pdf or html.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and I could solve it by doing the following. Note this is just for the HTML output.

1. Create an index.rst field with just the following:

`======================
Javadoc of the API XXX
======================`

As I am using the extension "sphinx.ext.autosectionlabel", this becomes a "level 1" section.

2. Modify the Make file so, once the HTML is generated, it replaces the index.html of the section "Javadoc of the API XXX" with the Javadoc of my API.

After this change, on the toctree I have a link to "Javadoc of the API XXX" and when you click it, you see the Javadoc.

I know is not the *proper way* of doing it, but it is the only that I have come up with after many Google searches.